# How to get tables using quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz and spring. In my main class I used an XML file to get the hibernate properties as below:

```
String conf[] = {"Config.xml"};
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(conf);
        TestProgram unittest=applicationContext.getBean(TestProgram.class);     
        unittest.testMethod(unittest);
```

In my job class I tried to retrieve the data from database as below:

```
 List<UserMasterVO> userMasterVO=userMasterService.findAll();
 System.out.println("userMasterVO..."+userMasterVO);
 for(int index=0;index<userMasterVO.size();index++)
     System.out.println(userMasterVO.get(index));
```

But it results in a null pointer exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered your other question on the stackoverflow which will resolve your this issue as well.
[Data retrival using quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707383/data-retrival-using-quartz)